# How to create a payrate calculator for different payrates within each day?

Tags: python

I have a table of how many hours each employee worked for a week. They can start and end at any time of the day, including overnight shifts. But for each time period, there is a different payrate. For example, from 5am-5pm Mon-Fri is $20/h. But 5pm-11:59pm Fri is $21/h. Sat and Sun full day is $23/h, and Monday 00:00am to 5am is again $20.

Say a worker starts 4pm Fri and ends 2am Sat, so the calculation comes (1 * 20) + (7 * 21) + (2 * 23). Doing these types of calculations for half a dozen workers across the whole week is time consuming and prone to making mistakes.

Instead of doing this manually, how can I write a program to take inputs of the day, start and end time and then calculate what the pay should be?

Not necessarily looking for code (although that would be helpful), but a way to break this down into a way that can be coded.

Answer (score 0):

```
payrates = {'p1':20, 'p2': 21, 'p3':23, 'p4':20}
#p1 = 5am-5pm Mon-Fri
#p2 = 5pm-11:59pm Fri
#p3 = Sat and Sun full day is $23/h
#p4 = Monday 00:00am to 5am
name = input("Please Enter Staff's Name: ")
stop = ''
totalpay=0
while True:
    wrate = input('Enter payrate type: ')
    hours = input('No of Hours worked: ')
    pay = payrates[wrate] * int(hours)
    totalpay += pay
    print(f'Subtotal = {totalpay}')
    stop = input('Press Enter to continue or type "stop" to finish: ')
    if stop == 'stop':
        break
    else:
        continue
print(f'Total pay for {name} is {totalpay}')
```

Here, I've simply created a dictionary that stores that various pay rates(p1,p2,p3,p4), then with a while loop, i can input the payrate and number of hours worked. Within the loop, I get the total pay calculated, and generate the final value.

This is a basic illustration, in a situation where you have many workers, you can have a dictionary hold all work details of each worker(something like `{'victor':{'p1':7, p2:2, p3:1}, 'david': {'p1':8, 'p2':1, 'p3':3},...}`, in which case you can run an iteration through the workers dictionary to generate their respective total pay. You may use `pandas` if your records are much.